# Operator precedence in boost::spirit?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I made some tests using the spirit mini_c sample. Unfortunately it does not keep the operator precedence as expected:

```
int main()
{
    return 3 > 10 || 3 > 1;
}
```

evaluates to 0.

```
return (3 > 10) || (3 > 1);
```

returns 1

I tried to move the definition of "||" and "&&" to the very top in the constructor of

```
template <typename Iterator>
expression<Iterator>::expression(
```

but that does not change anything. How can that be fixed. I am using boost 1.3.38.

Comment: I've never used Boost.Spirit, but I don't see how anything it defines could possibly make a difference here.  You have nothing but primitives, and you can't overload the built in operators.

Comment: I have another question considering this sample. Maybe you can help with that too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591533/implementing-not-in-boostspirit-mini-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Confirmed, that's a bug in the mini_c example related to operator precedence. I committed a fix to SVN, which will be available in Boost V1.45. Here is what I changed in the header file mini_cb.hpp:

old code:

```
equality_expr =
    relational_expr
    >> *(   ("==" > relational_expr     [op(op_eq)])
        |   ("!=" > relational_expr     [op(op_neq)])
        )
    ;

relational_expr =
    logical_expr
    >> *(   ("<=" > logical_expr        [op(op_lte)])
        |   ('<' > logical_expr         [op(op_lt)])
        |   (">=" > logical_expr        [op(op_gte)])
        |   ('>' > logical_expr         [op(op_gt)])
        )
    ;

logical_expr =
    additive_expr
    >> *(   ("&&" > additive_expr       [op(op_and)])
        |   ("||" > additive_expr       [op(op_or)])
        )
    ;
```

new code:

```
equality_expr =
    logical_expr
    >> *(   ("==" > logical_expr        [op(op_eq)])
        |   ("!=" > logical_expr        [op(op_neq)])
        )
    ;

logical_expr =
    relational_expr
    >> *(   ("&&" > relational_expr     [op(op_and)])
        |   ("||" > relational_expr     [op(op_or)])
        )
    ;

relational_expr =
    additive_expr
    >> *(   ("<=" > additive_expr       [op(op_lte)])
        |   ('<' > additive_expr        [op(op_lt)])
        |   (">=" > additive_expr       [op(op_gte)])
        |   ('>' > additive_expr        [op(op_gt)])
        )
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the same, but i forgot to modify the parameters inside the definitions.

Comment: Hello Hartmut. Today - 1 1/2 Years later i found out, that the code is still not correct: "==" and "&&" must be evaluated at last - AFTER "==" and "!=", not before.