# Implementing "NOT" in boost::spirit mini_c

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I tried to modify the mini_c example of boost::spirit to match to my existing vocabulary.

I therefore added a operator "NOT that should behave equal as "!":

```
unary_expr =
        primary_expr
    |   ("NOT" > primary_expr           [op(op_not)]) // This does not work
    |   ('!' > primary_expr             [op(op_not)])
    |   ('-' > primary_expr             [op(op_neg)])
    |   ('+' > primary_expr)
    ;
```

I can compile the modified source code, but when i try to execute it it fails to parse. How can i solve this?

**EDIT:**
As my want to access external variables, i had made another modification in order to build a list of these variables when compiling:

```
identifier %=
    raw[lexeme[alpha >> *(alnum | '§' | '_' | '.' | '-' )]]
    ;
variable =
       identifier      [add_var(_1)]
    ;
```

Where add_var and identifier are defined as

```
rule<Iterator, std::string(), white_space> identifier;
function<var_adder> add_var;
```

If i don't use this modification, "NOT" can be used. With the modification, using "NOT" generates a parsing error.

**EDIT 2:**
The following conditional expressions do work though:

```
logical_expr =
    relational_expr
    >> *(  ("AND" > relational_expr     [op(op_and)])
        |   ("OR" > relational_expr     [op(op_or)])
        )
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your change the small test:

```
int main()
{
    return NOT 1;
}
```

parses successfully and returns `0`. So it is not obvious to me what doesn't work for you. Could you provide a failing input example as well, please?

Comment: The first change you made (the `identifier %= ...`) is not related to the problems you are seeing. It's the second change (the `variable = ...`) which is problematic. Essentially what you did is to allow implicit variable declarations by blindly adding any encountered identifier into the symbol table. This is not only dangerous, but in your case adds the `NOT` to that table as well, causing the errors at parse time.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply: Yes we do allow any unknown variables during parsing, because there are millions of possible references and its  much cheaper to check only for those few that are in the expressions parsed, than to add register all possible values in the parser. I though understand your explanation. But why do the strings for logical_expr do work (see edit in post). Thanks quite a lot.