# Implementing operator precedence with boost spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I was attempting to replicate [this example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation#C.2B.2B) in order to implement C++ like operator precedence rules (I started with a subset, but I eventually plan to add the others).

Try as I might, I could not get the grammar to parse a single binary operation. It would parse literals (44, 3.42, "stackoverflow") just fine, but would fail anything like `3 + 4`.

I did look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591146/operator-precedence-in-boostspirit), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387627/ast-and-operator-precedence-in-rule-definition) in an attempt to get my solution to work, but got the same result.

(In an attempt to keep things short, I'll post only the relevant bits here, the full code is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b9904ce8dbf9960))

Relevant data structures for the AST:

```
enum class BinaryOperator
{
    ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE, MODULO, LEFT_SHIFT, RIGHT_SHIFT, EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL, LOWER, LOWER_EQUAL, GREATER, GREATER_EQUAL,
};

typedef boost::variant<double, int, std::string> Litteral;

struct Identifier { std::string name; };

typedef boost::variant<
    Litteral, 
    Identifier,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<UnaryOperation>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<BinaryOperation>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<FunctionCall>
> Expression;

struct BinaryOperation
{
    Expression rhs, lhs;
    BinaryOperator op;

    BinaryOperation() {}
    BinaryOperation(Expression rhs, BinaryOperator op, Expression lhs) : rhs(rhs), op(op), lhs(lhs) {}
};
```

The grammar:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct BoltGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper, Program()>
{
    BoltGrammar() : BoltGrammar::base_type(start, "start")
    {
        equalOp.add("==", BinaryOperator::EQUAL)("!=", BinaryOperator::NOT_EQUAL);
        equal %= (lowerGreater >> equalOp >> lowerGreater);
        equal.name("equal");

        lowerGreaterOp.add("<", BinaryOperator::LOWER)("<=", BinaryOperator::LOWER_EQUAL)(">", BinaryOperator::GREATER)(">=", BinaryOperator::GREATER_EQUAL);
        lowerGreater %= (shift >> lowerGreaterOp >> shift);
        lowerGreater.name("lower or greater");

        shiftOp.add("<<", BinaryOperator::LEFT_SHIFT)(">>", BinaryOperator::RIGHT_SHIFT);
        shift %= (addSub >> shiftOp >> addSub);
        shift.name("shift");

        addSubOp.add("+", BinaryOperator::ADD)("-", BinaryOperator::SUBTRACT);
        addSub %= (multDivMod >> addSubOp >> multDivMod);
        addSub.name("add or sub");

        multDivModOp.add("*", BinaryOperator::MULTIPLY)("/", BinaryOperator::DIVIDE)("%", BinaryOperator::MODULO);
        multDivMod %= (value >> multDivModOp >> value);
        multDivMod.name("mult, div, or mod");

        value %= identifier | litteral | ('(' > expression > ')');
        value.name("value");

        start %= qi::eps >> *(value >> qi::lit(';'));
        start.name("start");

        expression %= identifier | litteral | equal;
        expression.name("expression");

        identifier %= qi::lexeme[ascii::char_("a-zA-Z") >> *ascii::char_("0-9a-zA-Z")];
        identifier.name("identifier");

        litteral %= qi::double_ | qi::int_ | quotedString;
        litteral.name("litteral");

        quotedString %= qi::lexeme['"' >> +(ascii::char_ - '"') >> '"'];
        quotedString.name("quoted string");

        namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
        using namespace qi::labels;
        qi::on_error<qi::fail>(start, std::cout << phx::val("Error! Expecting: ") << _4 << phx::val(" here: \"") << phx::construct<std::string>(_3, _2) << phx::val("\"") << std::endl);
}

qi::symbols<char, BinaryOperator> equalOp, lowerGreaterOp, shiftOp, addSubOp, multDivModOp;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, BinaryOperation()> equal, lowerGreater, shift, addSub, multDivMod;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Expression()> value;

qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Program()> start;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Expression()> expression;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Identifier()> identifier;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Litteral()> litteral;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, std::string()> quotedString;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem (indeed) appears to be addressed in that [second answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387627/ast-and-operator-precedence-in-rule-definition).

Let me address some points:

0. the main problem was was compound:

   - your start rule is

     ```
       start     %= qi::eps >> *(value >> qi::lit(';'));
     ```

     this means it expects `value`s:

     ```
       value     %= identifier | literal | ('(' > expression > ')');
     ```

     however, since this parses **only** identifiers and literals or parenthesized subexpressions, the `3+4` binary operation will never be parsed.
   - your expression rule, again allows `identifier` or `literal` first (redundant/confusing):

     ```
       expression %= identifier | literal | equal;
     ```

I think you'd want something more like

```
    expression   = '(' >> expression >> ')' | equal | value;
    value        = identifier | literal;

    // and then
    start        = qi::eps >> -expression % ';';
```

0. your `BinaryOperation` productions allow *only* for the case where the operator is present; this breaks the way the rules are nested for operator precedence: a `multDivOp` would never be accepted as match, unless it happens to be followed by an `addSubOp`:

   ```
   addSub %= (multDivMod >> addSubOp >> multDivMod);
   multDivMod %= (value >> multDivModOp >> value);
   ```

This can best be fixed as shown in the linked answer:

```
    addSub     = multDivMod >> -(addSubOp     >> multDivMod);
    multDivMod = value      >> -(multDivModOp >> value);
```

where you can use semantic actions to build the AST nodes "dynamically":

```
    addSub     = multDivMod >> -(addSubOp     >> multDivMod) [ _val = phx::construct<BinaryOperation>(_val, _1, _2) ];
    multDivMod = value      >> -(multDivModOp >> value)      [ _val = phx::construct<BinaryOperation>(_val, _1, _2) ];
```

This beats the 'tedious" declarative approach hands-down (which leads to a lot of backtracking, see e.g. [Boost spirit poor performance with Alternative parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242408/boost-spirit-poor-perfomance-with-alternative-parser))

0. the literal rule will parse an integer as a double, because it isn't strict:

   ```
   literal   %= qi::double_ | qi::int_ | quotedString;
   ```

   you can fix this like:

   ```
   qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double> > strict_double;

   literal      = quotedString | strict_double | qi::int_;
   ```
1. `FunctionCall` should adapt `functionName` as an `Identifier` (not `std::string`)

   ```
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(FunctionCall, (Identifier, functionName)(std::vector<Expression>, args))
   ```
2. You `Expression` `operator<<` could (should) be a `boost::static_visitor` so that you

   - eliminate magic type switch numbers
   - get compiler checking of completeness of the switch
   - can leverage overload resolution to switch on variant member types

Using c++11, the code could still be inside the one function:

```
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Expression& expr)
    {
        os << "Expression ";
        struct v : boost::static_visitor<> {
            v(std::ostream& os) : os(os) {}
            std::ostream& os;

            void operator()(Literal         const& e) const { os << "(literal: "    << e                           << ")"; }
            void operator()(Identifier      const& e) const { os << "(identifier: " << e.name                      << ")"; }
            void operator()(UnaryOperation  const& e) const { os << "(unary op: "   << boost::fusion::as_vector(e) << ")"; }
            void operator()(BinaryOperation const& e) const { os << "(binary op: "  << boost::fusion::as_vector(e) << ")"; }
            void operator()(FunctionCall    const& e) const {
                os << "(function call: " << e.functionName << "("; 
                if (e.args.size() > 0) os << e.args.front();
                for (auto it = e.args.begin() + 1; it != e.args.end(); it++) { os << ", " << *it; }
                os << ")";
            }
        };
        boost::apply_visitor(v(os), expr);
        return os;
    }
```

0. you can use the `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES` macro to name your rules

   ```
   BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
       (start)(expression)(identifier)(literal)(quotedString)
       (equal)(lowerGreater)(shift)(addSub)(multDivMod)(value)
   )
   ```
1. you should include from the `spirit/include/` directory, which then relays to `spirit/home/` or `phoenix/include/` instead of including them directly.

Here is a fully working sample, that also improved the grammar rules for readability **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c029965fb1cf3db)**:

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

enum class UnaryOperator
{
    NOT,
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const UnaryOperator op)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case UnaryOperator::NOT:   return os << "!";
        case UnaryOperator::PLUS:  return os << "+";
        case UnaryOperator::MINUS: return os << "-";
    }

    assert(false);
}

enum class BinaryOperator
{
    ADD,        SUBTRACT,      MULTIPLY, DIVIDE,
    MODULO,
    LEFT_SHIFT, RIGHT_SHIFT,
    EQUAL,      NOT_EQUAL,
    LOWER,      LOWER_EQUAL,
    GREATER,    GREATER_EQUAL,
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BinaryOperator op)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case BinaryOperator::ADD:           return os << "+";
        case BinaryOperator::SUBTRACT:      return os << "-";
        case BinaryOperator::MULTIPLY:      return os << "*";
        case BinaryOperator::DIVIDE:        return os << "/";
        case BinaryOperator::MODULO:        return os << "%";
        case BinaryOperator::LEFT_SHIFT:    return os << "<<";
        case BinaryOperator::RIGHT_SHIFT:   return os << ">>";
        case BinaryOperator::EQUAL:         return os << "==";
        case BinaryOperator::NOT_EQUAL:     return os << "!=";
        case BinaryOperator::LOWER:         return os << "<";
        case BinaryOperator::LOWER_EQUAL:   return os << "<=";
        case BinaryOperator::GREATER:       return os << ">";
        case BinaryOperator::GREATER_EQUAL: return os << ">=";
    }

    assert(false);
}

typedef boost::variant<
    double, 
    int, 
    std::string
> Literal;

struct Identifier
{
    std::string name;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Identifier, (std::string, name))

struct UnaryOperation;
struct BinaryOperation;
struct FunctionCall;

typedef boost::variant<
    Literal, 
    Identifier,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<UnaryOperation>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<BinaryOperation>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<FunctionCall>
> Expression;

struct UnaryOperation
{
    Expression rhs;
    UnaryOperator op;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(UnaryOperation, (Expression,rhs)(UnaryOperator,op))

struct BinaryOperation
{
    Expression rhs;
    BinaryOperator op;
    Expression lhs;

    BinaryOperation() {}
    BinaryOperation(Expression rhs, BinaryOperator op, Expression lhs) : rhs(rhs), op(op), lhs(lhs) {}
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(BinaryOperation, (Expression,rhs)(BinaryOperator,op)(Expression,lhs))

struct FunctionCall
{
    Identifier functionName;
    std::vector<Expression> args;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(FunctionCall, (Identifier, functionName)(std::vector<Expression>, args))

struct Program
{
    std::vector<Expression> statements;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Program, (std::vector<Expression>, statements))

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Expression& expr)
{
    os << "Expression ";
    struct v : boost::static_visitor<> {
        v(std::ostream& os) : os(os) {}
        std::ostream& os;

        void operator()(Literal         const& e) const { os << "(literal: "    << e                           << ")"; }
        void operator()(Identifier      const& e) const { os << "(identifier: " << e.name                      << ")"; }
        void operator()(UnaryOperation  const& e) const { os << "(unary op: "   << boost::fusion::as_vector(e) << ")"; }
        void operator()(BinaryOperation const& e) const { os << "(binary op: "  << boost::fusion::as_vector(e) << ")"; }
        void operator()(FunctionCall    const& e) const {
            os << "(function call: " << e.functionName << "("; 
            if (e.args.size() > 0) os << e.args.front();
            for (auto it = e.args.begin() + 1; it != e.args.end(); it++) { os << ", " << *it; }
            os << ")";
        }
    };
    boost::apply_visitor(v(os), expr);
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Program& prog)
{
    os << "Program" << std::endl << "{" << std::endl;
    for (const Expression& expr : prog.statements) 
    { 
        std::cout << "\t" << expr << std::endl; 
    }
    os << "}" << std::endl;

    return os;
}

template<typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct BoltGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper, Program()>
{
    BoltGrammar() : BoltGrammar::base_type(start, "start")
    {
        using namespace qi::labels;

        equalOp.add
            ("==", BinaryOperator::EQUAL)
            ("!=", BinaryOperator::NOT_EQUAL);
        lowerGreaterOp.add
            ("<", BinaryOperator::LOWER)
            ("<=", BinaryOperator::LOWER_EQUAL)
            (">", BinaryOperator::GREATER)
            (">=", BinaryOperator::GREATER_EQUAL);
        shiftOp.add
            ("<<", BinaryOperator::LEFT_SHIFT)
            (">>", BinaryOperator::RIGHT_SHIFT);
        addSubOp.add
            ("+", BinaryOperator::ADD)
            ("-", BinaryOperator::SUBTRACT);
        multDivModOp.add
            ("*", BinaryOperator::MULTIPLY)
            ("/", BinaryOperator::DIVIDE)
            ("%", BinaryOperator::MODULO);

        equal        = lowerGreater [ _val=_1 ] >> -(equalOp        >> lowerGreater) [ _val = phx::construct<BinaryOperation>(_val, _1, _2) ];
        lowerGreater = shift        [ _val=_1 ] >> -(lowerGreaterOp >> shift)        [ _val = phx::construct<BinaryOperation>(_val, _1, _2) ];
        shift        = addSub       [ _val=_1 ] >> -(shiftOp        >> addSub)       [ _val = phx::construct<BinaryOperation>(_val, _1, _2) ];
        addSub       = multDivMod   [ _val=_1 ] >> -(addSubOp       >> multDivMod)   [ _val = phx::construct<BinaryOperation>(_val, _1, _2) ];
        multDivMod   = value        [ _val=_1 ] >> -(multDivModOp   >> value)        [ _val = phx::construct<BinaryOperation>(_val, _1, _2) ];

        start        = qi::eps >> -expression % ';';
        expression   = '(' >> expression >> ')' | equal | value;
        value        = identifier | literal;
        identifier   = qi::lexeme[ascii::char_("a-zA-Z") >> *ascii::char_("0-9a-zA-Z")];

        qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double> > strict_double;

        literal      = quotedString | strict_double | qi::int_;
        quotedString = qi::lexeme['"' >> +(ascii::char_ - '"') >> '"'];

        qi::on_error<qi::fail>(start, std::cout << phx::val("Error! Expecting: ") << _4 << phx::val(" here: \"") << phx::construct<std::string>(_3, _2) << phx::val("\"") << std::endl);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(expression)(identifier)(literal)(quotedString)
                (equal)(lowerGreater)(shift)(addSub)(multDivMod)(value)
                )
    }

    qi::symbols<char, BinaryOperator> equalOp, lowerGreaterOp, shiftOp, addSubOp, multDivModOp;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Expression()>  equal,  lowerGreater,  shift,  addSub,  multDivMod;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Expression()>  value;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Program()>     start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Expression()>  expression;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Identifier()>  identifier;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, Literal()>     literal;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, std::string()> quotedString;
};

typedef std::string::iterator Iterator;
typedef boost::spirit::ascii::space_type Skipper;

int main()
{
    BoltGrammar<Iterator, Skipper> grammar;

    std::string str("3; 4.2; \"lounge <c++>\"; 3 + 4;");

    Program prog;
    Iterator iter = str.begin(), last = str.end();
    bool r = phrase_parse(iter, last, grammar, ascii::space, prog);

    if (r && iter == last)
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded: " << prog << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing failed, remaining: " << std::string(iter, last) << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Parsing succeeded: Program
{
    Expression (literal: 3)
    Expression (literal: 4.2)
    Expression (literal: lounge <c++>)
    Expression (binary op: (Expression (literal: 3) + Expression (literal: 4)))
}
```

Comment: I have a similar case: I want to parse expressions, but I want them to be nested. I.e. `(4 + 3) == (5 + 3);` (or more specifically in my case `HoldsAt() & Pos() -> Pos() & HoldsAt() -> Unsafe()`) should be possible? Should I make a seperate question? Also why are some rules defined double?

Comment: That was a copy paste error - the [;live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c029965fb1cf3db) had it correctly though.

Comment: Regarding your question, yes, make it a separate question. Nesting is already supported, and implemented here. I'm not sure what your example (with the holdsat / ->) is supposed to do, so when you post a question you  could clarify that a little bit.

Comment: I made a very (very) extensive example with complete C++-compatible operator precedence/associativity [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60846101/85371) in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/210289?m=49164574#49164574) and you can see that code [on github](https://github.com/sehe/qi-extended-parser-evaluator) if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks! But the example `(3 + 4) == (4 + 3);` results in `Parsing failed, remaining: == (4 + 3);`. Am I doing something wrong then? Also I dont really see unlimited nesting in the code. I can only do one equal right? (Of course before the `;`) I can't for example do `4 == 4 == 3` I know its not semanticly correct, but just as an example.